# Find path length between two nodes of Dbpedia graph network, without knowing the underlying property path

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need to find the path length between any two nodes of Dbpedia graph,if there exists any connection between them. At this moment only start and end nodes are known to me and connected property paths are not known. So,I am attempting to write SPARQL query like:

```
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select dbp:Video dbo:VideoGame (count(?mid) as ?length) 
where {
  dbp:Video (<>|!<>)* ?mid .
  ?mid (<>|!<>)+ dbo:VideoGame .
}
group by dbp:Video dbo:VideoGame
```

Here I want to find path length between **Video** and **VideoGame**. But it is giving error like :

> syntax error at 'dbo:VideoGame' before '}'

Can anyone help to write the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

The error message may be misleading.  One issue I see is that you can't select constants, only variables.  You can try some bind statements to turn them into variables:

```
PREFIX dbo:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?vid ?vidGame (count(?mid) as ?length) 
where {
  BIND(dbp:Video AS ?vid)
  BIND(dbo:VideoGame AS ?vidGame)
  ?vid (<>|!<>)* ?mid .
  ?mid (<>|!<>)+ ?vidGame .
}
group by ?vid ?vidGame
```

Comment: Now it is giving another error: 

**Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory.  use t_distinct, t_max or more T_MAX_memory options to limit the search or increase the pool**

Comment: When I am trying to run this query from https://dbpedia.org/sparql , It is giving the error:     **Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: The list of return values contains '*' but the pattern does not contain variables**. Can anyone help?

Comment: You may try using a LIMIT to prevent exceeding the byte limit.  In terms of the Virtuoso error, you may want to check with the vendor.